# Laptop shuts down upon waking from suspend

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, 14.04, power-management, suspend

The computer enters suspend either by closing lid, choosing suspend from the top-right drop down, or hitting the power button and pressing suspend. It doesn't matter.

I then attempt to wake the computer either by opening the lid (if it was closed) or hitting the power button. Again, doesn't matter.

The computer will then immediately shutdown about 50% of the time. It seems to be more likely to shut down the longer it has been on suspend.

I took a snapshot of /var/log/pm-suspend.log after a successfully resume and a shutdown. The only difference (outside of timestamps of course) was that a successful resume, after reporting the success of various suspend hooks, writes:

```
Thu Jul  5 21:36:45 PDT 2012: performing suspend
Thu Jul  5 21:37:10 PDT 2012: Awake.
Thu Jul  5 21:37:10 PDT 2012: Running hooks for resume
```

and then reports successful resume hooks. When it shuts down, the log ends at "performing suspend". I diffed the two files so I know this is the only difference.

Thus, it looks like it's not even trying to wake up.

Would love some ideas on this one. I've scoured the web but can't seem to find anyone else running into the same issue (it seems more common that the computer shuts down upon entering suspend, or only on hitting the power button to wake, and haven't seen any that are random like mine). I'll update with any requested information.

EDIT:

Forgot to give my laptop's details! I'm running 12.04, 64 bit, on a Dell Inspiron 1420 with a Intel Core 2 Duo, 1.5GHz. No graphics card. 2G of ram. I recently had to disassemble and reassemble it (had to install a fan), and so could have messed something up in that process.

UPDATE:

I've upgraded to 12.10 and am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For several people, this was an issue with NVIDIA drivers and was solved by installing the latest proprietary drivers. If you, like myself, have an NVIDIA Optimus graphics card, the hardware is unsupported for suspend operations. To update your drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I hope that this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a NVIDIA card (no graphics card). Thanks though! I've added my computer's details to the question.