# Dell Studio 15, Turnoff after suspend due to overheat, and does not turnon the fan as well

Tags: suspend, bug-reporting, fan, sleep, temperature

I am new to Ubuntu and linux as well, the thing is...
I got strange problem with my laptop, I am not sure is the problem with my hardware or the os

I got: Dell Studio 15 (ATI Graphics Card) with Ubuntu 12.10_64bit version installed

Issue is... when I **suspend(sleep)** the laptop either by command or by turning the flap off, it does suspend perfectly, **but** when I **wakes it up,** It starts and after few minutes around **15-20 it turns off** automatically, after reproduction of the error,

I realize that **the fan is not starting after waking up the laptop,** so the laptop starts but not the fan so, it shut down when it gets overheated,

can anyone please, help me with this, or show me how to solve this issues.
Thanks
Nixit Patel

Comment: Which video driver are you using? Opensource or AMD?

Comment: I haven't installed any, I tried to install it but it was messing the screen graphincs

Comment: I've tried AMD driver

Comment: What video card model is it using? Dell website does not have that info.

Comment: VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series]

Comment: after your post, I'd tried to install the driver again as mentioned hear http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200, but it seems not working for me

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

most probably installing the correct VGA driver can reduce overheating. To install correct VGA driver

#### you need to do some simple things if your using ubuntu 12.10

1. first go to software center and type drivers.
2. in there find additional drivers. and install it.
3. after installation complete open it. it will search drivers for your VGA card. **warning! do not close it. because additional drivers not working properly in 12.10 so once you close you cannot find it anywhere. then you must remove it and re-install it again through software center.**
4. install all available VGA drivers for your machine.
5. after installation complete it will ask you to restart. you done!.
6. after restart go to Settings >  Details there you can see your VGA name and type.

Comment: I've tried using this link but this even messes screen rendering

Comment: what is your ATI card series?

Comment: RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series]

Answer (score 0):

Take a live ubuntu/Other OS pendrive try to boot from that and see if that's the case hmm the best would be if you have second OS installed on the same laptop where you can identify it is with ubuntu or the system , fan normally works when cpu sensor reports temperature but above i guess is the fast way to get started isolating the issue.

Comment: I have windows booted on the same pc but its not the problem, should I try with some other live os

Comment: Patel , you mean the fan runs after coming back sleep mode in Win install? machine doesn't get hot ? and doesn't shutdown   , can you please share the error message that you receive before the machine shutdown or is it fast one ? that you cannot get ?

Comment: yes in win it works perfect, and in ubuntu it doesn't give any error to me it just shut down just like power off, but I feel the heat and seen the temperature of the gpu, it was hot

Comment: It can be the cpu also if fan don't turn on.

Answer (score 0):

Patel hope this link helps you , this is pointing to install Orignal driver from Chip manufacturer /hardware vendor website rather then generic please find the link below.

[Laptop shuts down upon waking from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160681/laptop-shuts-down-upon-waking-from-suspend)